# Using a list to check if word from the list is anywhere within a Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

I am trying to check if any values within df1 in the Value column match to df2 [which will be a list]. Below will show you the structure of both.

My current DataFrames:
df1:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1256 | AMD left out early in the morning |
| 1546 | Jessica will need to be picked up from ORD |
| 7877 | (TBA) |
| 3794 | BLT might be crowded |
| 8946 | iPod was found at (SMH) |
| 4568 | ATL |
| 5669 | SAN |

df2:[a list]

| AIRPORTS |
| --- |
| AMD |
| TBA |
| BLT |
| SMH |
| ATL |

desired output:

| ID | Value | Match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1256 | AMD left out early in the morning | True |
| 1546 | Jessica will need to be picked up from ORD | False |
| 7877 | (TBA) | True |
| 3794 | BLT might be crowded | True |
| 8946 | iPod was found at (SMH) | True |
| 4568 | ATL | True |
| 5669 | SAN | False |

Comment: `df1['Match'] = df1['Value'].str.contains(fr"\b({'|'.join(df2['AIRPORTS'])})\b")`